# Portable Xampp with own default webpage

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, portable-executable

ich want to get an xampp oder another apache webserver, for portable usage with my custom website in the root. Is there a reason, that i only get an .exe for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XAMMP... I dont think it's that portable (xampp-portable-win32-1.8.3-4-VC11.exe). It still requires installing and it's not lightweight when unpacked (633MB), probably the most bloated ive ever seen.

There are lots of other WAMP stacks that are lighter and more portable, just do a s search "WAMP's portable", here are just a few:

- USBwebserver - http://www.usbwebserver.net/en/
- server2go - http://www.server2go-web.de/
- UwAmp - http://www.uwamp.com/en/
- Z-WAMP - http://zwamp.sourceforge.net/
- WDStak (my own, which has no install just run the exe, though I just put a shortcut to it from dropbox, then within the interface it's as simple as clicking start and stop) - http://icodes.it/